sed replace partially linux path
I have 2 text files i need to compare in a linux environment. They are coming from 2 different sources. They both contain their source path, so the comparison will fail because of that.
However, only the beginning of their path is different: at some point , the end of the path has to identical.
file1 contains:
file = import('/source-1/random/path/to/the/file/work/source/file.txt' , "corner")

file2 contains:
file = import('/s_2/file/work/source/file.txt' , "corner")

So i would like to find whatever is in between the first / and work and replace it by a * for example, so at the end i get:
in file1:
file = import('*/w/source/file.txt' , "corner")

in file2:
file = import('*/w/source/file.txt' , "corner")

and my diff will not fail anymore because of that.
I tried many things but nothing really worked :(  That's why i kindly request your help now :)
my best attempt did not give anything :
([\/][a-zA-Z09]*[+-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*/work

Removing the whole line would defeat the purpose of comparing the files :( that would be easier though . I need to remove the first part of the linux path (from the first / to the word "work" ) . It's not everytime the same literal string, except that "work" and whatever goes after "work" should be identical
thanks a lot for your great help :)

Please show what you feel is your best attempt. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Could you just remove that line completely when comparing?

E.g. diff <(grep -v 'file = import' file1) <(grep -v 'file = import' file2)

Can you clarify what you want to replace? Is it always the same literal string in each file, or a more general pattern?

my best attempt did not give anything : ([/][a-zA-Z09][+-_][a-zA-Z0-9])/work
Removing the whole line would defeat the purpose of comparing the files :(  that would be easier though .
I need to remove the first part of the linux path (from the first / to the word "work" ) . It's not everytime the same literal string, except that "work" and whatever goes after "work" should be identical

Please put it in the question and show the full  sed command.

[a-zA-Z09]*[+-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]* can be simplified to [a-zA-Z0-9+_-]* There's no need to repeat [a-zA-Z0-9]*.

Why not just \/.*\/work?

Is 09 supposed to be 0-9?

Your regexp doesn't match multiple / before work

awk '
    { key=$0; sub("/.*/work/","*/w/",key) }
    NR==FNR { f1key=key; next }
    f1key != key { print "<", f1key ORS ">", key; exit 1 }
' file1 file2

The above creates a key from the input:
$ awk '{key=$0; sub("/.*/work/","*/w/",key); print FILENAME, key}' file1 file2
file1 file = import('*/w/source/file.txt' , "corner")
file2 file = import('*/w/source/file.txt' , "corner")

then compares the keys from both files and outputs nothing and exits success if they are identical or prints a diff-like output and exits with an error status if they are different, e.g.:
$ head file?
==> file1 <==
file = import('/source-1/random/path/to/the/file/work/source/file.txt' , "corner")

==> file2 <==
file = import('/s_2/file/work/source/file.txt' , "corner")

==> file3 <==
file = import('/s_2/file/work/some_other/file.txt' , "corner")


$ awk '{key=$0; sub("/.*/work/","*/w/",key)} NR==FNR{f1key=key; next} f1key != key{ print "<", f1key ORS ">", key; exit 1}' file1 file2
$


$ awk '{key=$0; sub("/.*/work/","*/w/",key)} NR==FNR{f1key=key; next} f1key != key{ print "<", f1key ORS ">", key; exit 1}' file1 file3
< file = import('*/w/source/file.txt' , "corner")
> file = import('*/w/some_other/file.txt' , "corner")

